# Печать кортежей в списке без циклов. Почему None выводится

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задача на функциональное программирование (циклы и т.п. использовать нельзя).
По данному числу N выведите все перестановки чисел от 1 до N в лексикографическом порядке.
Входные данные:

```
3
```

Требуемый формат вывода программы:

```
123
132
213
231
312
321
```

Я написал код, который работает, но выдаёт кроме результата ещё None.

Мой код:

```
import itertools
import functools
prints = functools.partial(print, sep='')
print(
    *itertools.starmap(
        prints,
        sorted(
            itertools.permutations(
                range(1,
                      int(input()) + 1)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Получающийся вывод для значения 3:

```
123
132
213
231
312
321
None None None None None None
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как вывести кортежи в требуемом виде

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print()` эта функция, которая всегда `None` возвращает:

```
print(print(1))
```

Вывод:

```
1
None
```

Если не хотите, чтобы `None` печатался, не следует результат `print()` печатать.

---

Чтобы вывести все перестановки чисел от 1 до N в лексикографическом порядке:

```
from itertools import permutations 

N = int(input())
print(*map(''.join, permutations(map(str, range(1, N+1)))), sep='\n')
```

Вывод для `N=3`:

```
123
132
213
231
312
321
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
from itertools import permutations 
from browser import document

@document["mybutton"].bind("click") 
def on_click(event):
    N = int(document["zone"].value)
    print(*map(''.join, permutations(map(str, range(1, N+1)))), sep='\n')
</script><input id="zone" value="3"><button id="mybutton">Запустить</button></body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить циклы на рекурсию

```
def foo(start, end, <необходимые параметры>):
    if start >= end:
        return 0
    else:
        ...
        тело "цикла"
        ...
        return foo(start-1, end, <необходимые параметры>)
```

По такому примеру. По принципу работы почти тоже самое что и `for i in range()`
И использовать тот алгоритм который вы могли бы выразить циклом. Это не считается циклом который вам запрещено использовать, и активно используется в функ.программировании

Comment: def - не укладывается в правила. Максимум - lambda

Answer (score 1):

Итоговый принятый код, благодаря @jfs

```
from itertools import permutations 
print(
    *map(
        ''.join,
        permutations(
            map(
                str,
                range(
                    1,
                    int(input()) + 1
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    sep='\n'
)
```